# How to hide shadow copy in windows

Tags: windows

**OS:** Windows server 2008 enterprise R2 as the file server
**Function:** shadow copy
**Question:** Need to hide the 'Restore previous versions' from users, only administrator can see the previous version?

Answer (score 0):

Make an logon script that does the following registry modification "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer"
"NoPreviousVersionsPage"
"1" 
for normal users, then you can keep it on for Administrator users. Please test this before implementing it